# How do I turn off or ignore key repeat for my curses application?

Tags: c++, c, input, curses, pdcurses

So I recently found curses (specifically [PDcurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/)) and I'm just getting into it. Right now I'm trying to write a little space shooter type game with it and it's worked fine so far for rendering and getting menu type input, but now when I go into the game, I've noticed that key repeat is pretty bad for action games. I need to be able to hold the key and move my avatar every single frame that the key is down. I know how to do this with a normal Win32 application, but I don't have a window and therefore I don't have a wndproc and I can't control the messages the console recieves :/

I don't expect this is something for curses to handle, though if it can that would be awesome, I was really just looking for a work-around that plays nicely with curses.

I have tried cbreak(), nodelay() and raw() to no avail.

Additional info:

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
- PDcurses 3.4, from prebuilt binaries
- Windows 7 x64 Ultimate

Comment: I think a more interesting question is, "how do you tell when a key's been released?"  `getch()` won't tell you this.  I suspect the answer to both questions ends up being the same: design your input method so this annoyance isn't important.

Comment: Do you have a solution then? A way to avoid key bounce altogether in a win32 console? Because all of the ways I can think of to do input more effectively require a window (e.g. SDL, RAW Input, dinput)

Comment: I was thinking "remember that said key was pressed recently, and ignore the keypress"

Answer (score 2):

This is far from a complete solution, and I don't know how it'll interact with PDCurses, but it's an attempt:

In summary, grab the console's handle with `GetStdHandle()`, configure it for raw reading with `SetConsoleMode()`, and then read keys one at a time with `ReadConsoleInput()`.  I use a `std::set` to keep track of the currently pressed keys and so ignore repeats.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <set>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE h=GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD mode;
    BOOL success;
    success=GetConsoleMode(h, &mode);
    assert(success);
    mode &= ~(ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT | ENABLE_LINE_INPUT);
    mode |= ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT;
    success=SetConsoleMode(h, mode);
    assert(success);

    INPUT_RECORD buffer[10];
    std::set<WORD> keys_down;
    while (true)
    {
        DWORD count=0;
        success=ReadConsoleInput(h, buffer, 10, &count);
        if (!success)
        {
            continue;
        }
        for (size_t i=0;i<count;++i)
        {
            switch (buffer[i].EventType)
            {
            case KEY_EVENT:
            {
                WORD keycode=buffer[i].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode;
                if (buffer[i].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)
                {
                    if (keys_down.find(keycode)==keys_down.end())
                    {
                        std::cout<<"Key down: "<<keycode<<std::endl;
                        keys_down.insert(keycode);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (keys_down.find(keycode)!=keys_down.end())
                    {
                        std::cout<<"Key up:"<<keycode<<std::endl;
                        keys_down.erase(keycode);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            default: 
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does do exactly what I want to do, but it's compatibility with curses is probably nil, I will try it though. `mode &= ~(ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT | ENABLE_LINE_INPUT);` is actually available through curses via the `noecho()` and `cbreak()` functions respecively, but the `ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT` flag is probably the real root of the issue. I'll see if `getch()` is affected by it.
And thanks :)

Comment: Alas, `getch()` doesn't care :( I guess the windows functions are what you're supposed to use on windows anyway. I do this often where I try to apply a UNIX library to windows and then get mad at windows when it doesn't work

Comment: I think the point is, UNIX terminals aren't designed to offer functionality like this (key up notifications.)  If you're interested in writing a game with curses, it should be one that makes sense without a "hold-the-key-down" control.

Comment: That said, there shouldn't be any reason you couldn't render with PDCurses, and use Windows console functions for input.